# Trying to compile vim on OS X?

Tags: macos, vim, compilation

Following [this writeup](http://nerderati.com/2010/07/compiling-vim-with-ruby-integration-on-snow-leopard/)...

The compiled binary seems to work fine, but the installed binary fails (when running `make install`).

It seems to be failing on this step:

```
...
generating help tags
/usr/local/bin/vim -u NONE -esX -c "helptags ++t ." -c quit
dyld: Symbol not found: _environ
  Referenced from: /Users/neezer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/neezer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
make[2]: *** [vimtags] Trace/BPT trap
make[1]: [installrtbase] Error 2 (ignored)
```

I used this to configure:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-rubyinterp --enable-gui=no --disable-gpm
```

Like I said, I think it compiled correctly, because I can run `./src/vim` after `make` just fine (no errors). But when I try to run the installed version after `make install` in `/usr/local/bin/vim`, I get this (mirrors above):

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _environ
  Referenced from: /Users/neezer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/neezer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
[1]    13175 trace trap  vim
```

Running `which vim` verifies that it is trying to load the new binary in `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

My current version of Ruby is `ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]` via [RVM](https://rvm.io).

What's happening here?

And no: I don't want to just use MacVim instead...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Says right in the blog post:

> you’ve probably fallen prey to a (currently) not very well documented issue: Vim 7.2 does not support the integration of Ruby 1.9.x on Snow Leopard.

There's more information available in [this ticket](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/a34ba9d02c57af9a/57ab7457327c81d8).

But in summary, you have to link against Ruby 1.8.7, which is the version that ships with Snow Leopard anyway.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I had not ran into that error at all during compilation or version checking, but trying to run Command-T in the newly compiled binary threw it. As the "binary launch[ed] without any errors", I had already taken to "rejoicing in my own awesomeness" not thinking this applied to me, but running Command-T proved this to be a premature celebration. Taking those extra steps fixed the problem. Slightly unclear blog post... will write to the author about that. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this. Same problem - although thanks to RVM - I was able to simply switch to the 1.8.7 installed ruby and everything was fine.

Comment: I did switch with $ rvm use 1.8.7 and still got this:  $ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin10.8.0]
Coltrane:ggspree joe$ brew install https://raw.github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/master/duplicates/vim.rb $ which ruby
/Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby
Coltrane:ggspree joe$ vim --version | grep ruby
dyld: Symbol not found: _environ
  Referenced from: /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib --- Not sure what to do?

Answer (score 6):

Vim can't be compiled with Ruby 1.9.X (may be fixed in the future). You have to compile it with Ruby 1.8.X, if you want to use ruby integration.

If you use rbenv instead of rvm, you can change to ruby 1.8.7 or disable rbenv in your .zshenv or .bash_profile file, recompile vim and enable your current ruby again. This should work for OSX 10.6 too. I've tested this solution on OSX 10.7 and 10.8 only.

For zsh and rbenv:

```
# disable in your .zshenv for compile time. Just comment it out for comile time.
# eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

For bash and rbenv:

```
# disable in .bash_profile or .bashrc for compile time. Just comment it out for comile time.
# eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

For rvm, you can switch to system ruby (osx), recompile and switch back

```
rvm use system
brew uninstall vim
brew install vim
rvm use 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/); compiling vim then becomes:

```
$ sudo port install vim
```

EDIT: Correction; you would need the ruby mode:

```
$ sudo port install vim +ruby
```

MacPorts will then fetch all dependencies and sort all that headache out itself.

Comment: I don't use MacPorts anymore, but [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) instead. I found that there is an alternative formula for vim that includes 7.3 and ruby/python support, but running into issues regarding Ruby 1.9.2, so I'm trying to downgrade to 1.9.1 to see if that solves it... brew install https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/raw/master/duplicates/vim.rb

Comment: Interesting; I haven't seen Homebrew before but it looks good.  I will check it out if MacPorts becomes annoying :)