# Howto compile vim with ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, macos, vim, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

I tried to re-compile vim with ruby support because I noticed that vim was still using 1.8.7 (which is the default ruby version on Snow Leopard). Ruby 1.9.2 is installed via rvm.

When compiling with

```
./configure --enable-rubyinterp --enable-gui=no --disable-nls --enable-cscope --prefix=/Users/madhatter
```

I get the following error from make:

```
ld: library not found for -lruby.1.9.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [vim] Error 1
make: *** [first] Error 2
```

I then cloned the actual repository from googlecode and tried to build that. There were no errors in make, but starting vim resulted in the following error:

```
  dyld: Symbol not found: _environ
  Referenced from: /Users/madhatter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/madhatter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib
[1]    41782 trace trap  vim
```

Last thing I tried was adding some ruby information to the config.mk file

```
RUBY            = /Users/madhatter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby                            
RUBY_SRC        = if_ruby.c
RUBY_OBJ        = objects/if_ruby.o
RUBY_PRO        = if_ruby.pro
RUBY_CFLAGS     = -I/Users/madhatter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/Users/madhatter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0 -DRUBY_VERSION=19
RUBY_LIBS       = -lruby.1.9.1 -lpthread -ldl -lobjc
```

Any other ideas what might work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [Trying to compile vim on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114380/trying-to-compile-vim-on-os-x) for an answer. Basically the answer is that you can't right now without fixing Vim.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm using for vim + python

```
./configure --with-features=BIG --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-multibyte=yes --enable-cscope=yes
```

Looks like you're missing

```
--enable-rubyinterp=yes
```

Comment: AFAIK is `--enable-rubyinterp` the same as `--enable-rubyinterp=yes`. It did not change anything.