# How can I get vim to point to macvim? Where can I find macvim?

Tags: vim, macvim

I would like vim to point to macvim :)

Probably through an alias.

vim is here: `whereis vim
/usr/bin/vim`

macvim I can't find, e.g.
`whereis macvim` returns nothing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer is kind of the opposite of michaelmichael's and I've made it [quite a few times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9277437/546861):

MacVim comes with a CLI executable that you can use in place of Mac OS X's default Vim if you add a single alias to your `~/.bashrc`/`~/.profile`. No need to compile anything, no need to put MacVim in a special place, no need to overwrite default programs with symlinks

This way, you can stay in CLI-land and enjoy the power of a powerful/recent/fast Vim.

*EDIT*

MacVim is a native Mac OS X GUI version of Vim. It doesn't come preinstalled with your OS so you have to download it [from the Internet](https://github.com/downloads/b4winckler/macvim/MacVim-snapshot-64.tbz) or install it through homebrew (see michaelmichael's answer). Once it's installed, MacVim is where you have put it, plain and simple.

Because it's a full fledged GUI app, MacVim can't really be used as a drop-in replacement for the default Vim in the terminal.

```
`$ MacVim file.txt` will not work. `$ open -a macvim file.txt` will not work either.
```

You basically have two options: use the `mvim` CLI wrapper to open MacVim from the terminal or use an alias to MacVim's bundled CLI executable.

1. **The `mvim` wrapper**

   I think michaelmichael's answer could be a expanded a bit but the most important is said.

   *EDIT:* well scratch that.
2. **The bundled CLI executable**

   Just add this line (customized to reflect your system) to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or whatever file is run by your shell at startup:

   ```
   alias vim='/path/to/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'
   ```

   Open a new terminal window, `$ vim file.txt` should launch vim in your terminal window, just like the default `/usr/bin/vim` but with a lot more bells and whistles.

Comment: sounds good but I can't find where macvim is as indicated in the question

Comment: Well, your question is barely understandable, actually. See my edit.

Comment: Easier than `alias vim='/path/to/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim'` is simply: `vim='mvim -v'` followed by `alias vim="${vim}"`.  The reason it is good to create an environment variable called `vim` is because you may wish to use $vim in more than one bash statement.

Comment: Try `which mvim` to find out where macvim is located. `which` searches your $PATH and reports the first occurrence. I think @"Michael Durrant" meant `which` and not `whereis`.

Answer (score 12):

The MacVim distro comes with a script called `mvim` that takes exactly the same arguments as `vim`. Put `mvim` somewhere in your path. Then, just set the alias: `alias vim='mvim'`

If you want to completely override the system vim, an easy way is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Just install MacVim with `$brew install macvim --override-system-vim`. The `--override-system-vim` flag will create `mvim` symlinks to `vi`, `vim`, etc. You may find it a cleaner way to achieve the same goal. Plus, I prefer to use Homebrew as a package manager.

**EDIT:** Since you say you don't know where MacVim is, you may just want to [download the latest tarball](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases) for your system and start from scratch. There are three files: the MacVim application, the `mvim` script, and a README.

Put MacVim in your Applications folder. Put `mvim` somewhere in your path.

Going forward, you should look for `mvim` using `which` rather than `whereis`. E.g. `$which mvim #=> /usr/local/bin/mvim`

`which` returns the pathnames of the files which would be executed in the current environment. `whereis` checks the standard binary directories, and may miss files included in your personal path.

Alternately, use Homebrew, as I suggest above and it will manage the location of both files.

Comment: It's worth noting that `mvim` takes *exactly* the same arguments as `vim`. Also, the `-v` flag is **not** a good idea, as it actually puts Vim into Vi mode, which is almost never what you want. If you want a non-GUI MacVim then, well, just run `vim`!

Comment: Thanks for noting. I've removed the `-v` suggestion.

Comment: This is good but I still don't know where macvim or mvim is.  `mvim` at the command line gives `command not found` not surprisingly.

Comment: You need to install MacVim (and mvim), not surprisingly.

Answer (score 1):

After installing mvim, you can find where it is located with typing into terminal:

```
which mvim
```

On my system this gave me:

```
/usr/local/bin/mvim
```

Then you create an alias in .bash_profile by typing the following in your terminal, and hit enter:

```
echo alias vim='/usr/local/bin/mvim' >> .bash_profile
```

Restart your terminal and try typing:

```
vim .
```

This should launch mvim and not vim